# Percentage of each value in a row respective to first value

Tags: perl, awk

I've a big file which consisting the data in following format.

```
11      6       2       3
19      5       1       13
9       3       0       6
15      7       1       7
7       6       0       1
9       3       4       2
```

I want to calculate percentage of each value of a row starting from 2nd column respective to the first column value. Something like `(6/11)*100; (2/11)*100; (3/11)*100` for every row in the file.
Expected output

```
54.5  18.1 27.2
26.3  5.2  68.4
...
...
```

I've tried in awk,

```
awk '{a=($2/$1)*100; b=($3/$1)*100; c=($4/$1)*100}END{print a, b, c}'`
```

and the result is `awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=try FNR=27) fatal: division by zero attempted`. Is that only due to presence of 0 in some of rows or anything wrong with the awk oneliner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have zeros in some $1s. You need something like:

```
$ cat file
11      6       2       3
0       5       1       13
9       3       0       6
15      7       1       7
0       6       0       1
9       3       4       2

$ awk 'BEGIN{CONVFMT="%.1f"} {for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) $i=($1==0?"NaN":$i*100/$1)} 1' file
11 54.5 18.2 27.3
0 NaN NaN NaN
9 33.3 0 66.7
15 46.7 6.7 46.7
0 NaN NaN NaN
9 33.3 44.4 22.2
```

Replace "NaN" with whatever else you want displayed when $1 is zero if you don't like "NaN" (you should have included that case in your sample input).

Comment: Thats very nice. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Using perl from command line,

```
perl -lane 'print join "\t", map $F[0] ? $_*100/$F[0] : "Nan", @F[1..$#F]' file
```

Comment: @EdMorton tnx for comment.